# When upgrading Firebase database to version 9, event.value no longer works

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I recently upgraded firebase database to version 10, and the following code, which worked in version 8, no longer works.

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("schools").once().then((value){
  print(value);
  items = [];
  for(int i =0; i< value.value.length; i++){
    print(i);

    items.add(value.value[i].toString());
  }
  print(items.toString());
```

Now it says the getter "value" isnt defined. I couldn't find anything on the changelog that said it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually in Firestore, but the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write#read-data-once-with-once) says you would probably have to access it through the snapshot though.

Try something like

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("schools").once().then((value){
    print(value.snapshot);
    items = [];
    for(int i =0; i< value.snapshot.value?.length; i++){
        print(i);

        items.add(value.snapshot.value[i].toString());
    }
    print(items.toString());
}
```

Comment: didn't seem to work.  getter 'length' isn't defined.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your value, that is something you have to tell or figure out on your own. If you don't share the print outputs, this is all i can do for you